# How to get block to change width if text is longer then the width in a multilevel listless drop down navigation menu

Tags: css, navbar, nav

I have a listless multilevel drop down menu. I have a problem that if the text of the link is longer then the width the height of block does not expand and part of the link is outside the box.

I have a JSFiddle setup for it at https://jsfiddle.net/JoeyD473/x57d8jbg

```
<!-- HTML -->
<nav role="navigation" id="mainNavigationBar" class="nav_ul_1">
<div class="nav_li">
    <a href="/dnd_tools" class="nav_links">Home</a>
</div>
<div class="nav_li">
        <a href="/dnd_tools/initiative_tracker" class="nav_links">Initiative Tracker <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span></a>
  <div class="nav_ul_hidden">
    <div class="nav_li">
      <a href="/dnd_tools/initiative_tracker" class="nav_links">Encounters <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></span></a>
      <div class="nav_ul_hidden">
        <div class="nav_li">
          <a href="initiative_tracker/encounter/1">Test</a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav_li">
          <a href="initiative_tracker/encounter/2">Sort Test</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav_li">
      <a href="/dnd_tools/initiative_tracker/create_encounter" class="nav_links">Create Encounter</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 <div class="nav_li">
   <a href="/logout" class="nav_links">Logout</a>
 </div>
  </nav>
```

CSS

```
    #mainNavigationBar
{
    z-index:9999;
    height:50px;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #28343B 8%, #828C95 65%, #B5BDC8 100%);
    border:solid 1px #000000;
}

#mainNavigationBar > .nav_li
{
    padding:0 10px 0 10px;
}

#mainNavigationBar > .nav_li > a
{
    color:rgb(12, 81, 46);
    font-size:1.25em;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.nav_li
{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    height:49px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:49px;
    z-index:9999;
}

.nav_ul_1 .nav_ul_hidden
{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    color:rgb(12, 81, 46);
}

.nav_ul_1 .nav_ul_hidden a
{
    color:rgb(12, 81, 46);
    font-size:1em;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.nav_ul_1 .nav_ul_hidden .nav_li
{
    padding:0 10px 0 10px;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #28343B 8%, #828C95 65%, #B5BDC8 100%);
    color:rgb(12, 81, 46);
    min-width:100%;
    min-height: 49px;
    margin-top:10px;
    border-radius:25px 25px 25px 25px;
    border:rgb(12, 81, 46) 1px outset;
    box-shadow:5px 5px 10px 0 #0F0F0F;
}

.nav_ul_1 .nav_ul_hidden .nav_li:first-child
{
    padding:0 10px 0 10px;
    color:#000000;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:-10px;
    border-radius:25px 25px 25px 25px;
    box-shadow:5px 5px 10px 0 #0F0F0F;
}

.nav_ul_1 .nav_ul_hidden .nav_li .nav_ul_hidden .nav_li
{
    margin-left:10px;
}

.nav_ul_1 .nav_ul_hidden .nav_li .nav_ul_hidden .nav_li:first-child
{
    color:rgb(12, 81, 46);
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.nav_li:hover > .nav_ul_hidden
{
    display:block;
}

.nav_ul_hidden .nav_ul_hidden
{
    left:100%;
    top:0;
}
```

If you hover over initiative tracker and the then over encounters you will see the second link called "Sort Test" the word "Test" is not in the nice looking block but below it.

How can I get the block to increase the width (for all the links in that specific drop down) to fit the text?

Yes I am using Bootstrap, but I don't like their drop down because it is only one level and I wanted the possibility of unlimited drop down levels and the solutions I saw all required Javascript and I wanted it to be strictly CSS based. ANd though it shouldn't matter but just in case the backend is using Laravel 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this changes in your codes i.e. just add `width` of `100%` to `.nav_ul_hidden`

```
.nav_ul_1 .nav_ul_hidden
{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    color:rgb(12, 81, 46);
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: This seems to have done it. Thank you. I figured I was missing something stupid

Comment: @JoeyD473 Welcome :-)